# Is there a Donate Now type button that I can just plug into my drupal site?

Tags: payment-processor, drupal-8, donations, button, simple-donate-form

I am interested in creating a donate button that can be used on drupal8 as well as if someone wanted to add it to their own site.
I saw https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Single_click_donations_with_CiviCRM
And I see https://civicrm.org/extensions/simple-donate
But they both appear quite old.
Is there some recommended button configs, especially as it relates to a credit card or other payment processor?

Comment: It would be great if it were like a plugable block so that it can be placed in a menu or footer or on a regular node.  Thanks in advance for the advice

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to embed a form on another site then you should look at

- remoteform https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.remoteform
- drupal 8 webform https://youtu.be/oMgOprfJTWA